# POST request in R

Tags: r, api, http, post, httr

Trying to send POST request in R but didn't work. I tried:

```
require(httr)

token_endpoint = '...'
client_id = '...'
client_secret = 'pgGj9n4Sdl8cfM4cKNnjYcLVGSIyQxhm3ydCX3IRbdc='
scope = 'icdapi_access'
grant_type = 'client_credentials'

r <- POST(token_endpoint, add_headers('client_id'= client_id, 
                                            'client_secret'= client_secret, 
                                            'scope'= scope, 
                                            'grant_type'= grant_type))
```

with package `httr` following a Python version of this https://github.com/ICD-API/Python-samples/blob/master/sample.py

but I don't know where to find `access_token` in `r`

[image]

Also I don't know where should I

Comment: Please provide more detail as *didn't work* does not work for us. Errors? Undesired results?

Comment: @Parfait still getting the same table

Comment: My content is still raw

Comment: Aside - consider removing your API secrets/tokens. You may need a moderator to delete history for security reasons.

Comment: @Parfait gotcha

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you need to retrieve the `content` object in your response data and have it parsed. Consider sending `JSON` content type as a config parameter (i.e., unnamed parameter). Since it is json, convert the content with `rawToChar` and pass it into `jsonlite::fromJSON()`. You may need to dig inside `api_json` to retrieve needed data.

```r
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

...

response <- httr::POST(
    token_endpoint, 
    add_headers(
        'client_id'= client_id, 
        'client_secret'= client_secret, 
        'scope'= scope, 
        'grant_type'= grant_type)
    ),
    httr::content_type_json()
  )
  
api_json <- jsonlite::fromJSON(rawToChar(response$content))
```

Comment: Says invalid request following what you're writing here in `api_json`

Comment: What line returns the error? `POST`? To be clear, you did not receive *any* error in original above?

Comment: Just api_jason writes invalid request

Comment: That means you receive a bad request. I tried digging alternative routes but keep getting 400 bad request. Raise an issue with Git authors for an R version in addition to PHP/Python/JS versions. I did confirm sample works in Python. Strange it cannot translate easily. See [trials](https://pastebin.com/gKLXzpa2). Please post if you every find a solution. Good luck!